# Using Kuberentes Objects for Pessimistic Locking

Tags: kubernetes, locking

wondering if would be correct to use a Kubernetes object for pessimistic locking.

For example if I would like make sure that only one process (or service or pod) would process a set of resources. Could I use `ConfigMap` as a lock, so if two or more processes will try to CREATE a `ConfigMap` with the same name only one that is successful would aquire the lock the other would fail.

(The ConfigMap could contain all the supporting information like, creation date to support expiry)

Given the characteristics with etcd this should be fine.
https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/learning/api_guarantees/#consistency

There is a Lease object in Kubernetes what seems to be designed for this purpose:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/lease-v1/
(But not documented, and what I found is used for maintain information about node availability)

**So, would it be correct? what are the drawback of this approach?**

In case what would be the advantage of using zookeeper or redlock or other altertives?

(Ignoring the fact that this would possibly introduce high load to  the API Server)

thank you!

Comment: Have you already tried something (what)? Which version of Kubernetes do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely the case, since the consistency guarantees of Kubernetes API Server (and/or etc)

The leader election (see go-client, or fabric8 client [leader election](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/LeaderElectionTest.java) implementation, what is basically even a more complex form of pessimistic locking.